# Where to find the source code of this function?

Tags: c++, mysql, c

I am looking to find the source code of the C function `mysql_stmt_free_result()`

I searched everywhere but I didn't find out the the source code. I need to understand what exactly this function frees. The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-stmt-free-result.html) lacks information about what exactly is freed.

Comment: i thing it is written in java, and c isnt opensource man... so may be wont get the code.. but keep trying

Comment: @AshishRatan: The MySQL C API written in Java? What are you smoking?! Also: MySQL [is open source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/getting-source-tree.html), the langauge it was written in doesn't matter...

Comment: You know you can just download the source code, right?  http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version from [MySQL 5.6.11](http://osxr.org/mysql/source/libmysql/libmysql.c#4637):

```
my_bool STDCALL mysql_stmt_free_result(MYSQL_STMT *stmt)
 {
   DBUG_ENTER("mysql_stmt_free_result");

   /* Free the client side and close the server side cursor if there is one */
   DBUG_RETURN(reset_stmt_handle(stmt, RESET_LONG_DATA | RESET_STORE_RESULT |
                                 RESET_CLEAR_ERROR));
 }
```

Here is [the MySQL development repository](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mysql/mysql-server/5.7/files/).

Comment: Can you please provide some more code, functions `DBUG_ENTER` and `reset_stmt_handle`.

Comment: @We'reAllMadHere Please follow the link in my answer, you can find the definitions for these functions and macros in there.